Error in emacs: emacs after install evil: Native compiler error
emacs native compiler error
does anyone know what's wrong with this? I try to download evil for emacs but encounter a native compiler error, and doom-mode-line also has this problem
Error (use-package): evil/:catch: Native compiler error: (lambda (arg0 arg1 &optional arg2) (let ((f #'set-window-buffer)) (funcall f arg0 arg1 arg2))), "Compiling c:/Users/10747/AppData/Roaming/.emacs.d/eln-cache/29.1-ece58e2c/subr--trampoline-7365742d77696e646f772d627566666572_set_window_buffer_0.eln...
this is my evil config in init.el
(use-package evil
  :init
  (setq evil-want-integration t)
  (setq evil-want-keybinding nil)
  (setq evil-want-C-u-scroll t)
  (setq evil-want-C-i-jump nil)
  :config
  (evil-mode 1)
  ; use C-g to go to normal mode
  (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-g") 'evil-normal-state)

  ;; Use visual line motions even outside of visual-line-mode buffers
  (evil-global-set-key 'motion "j" 'evil-next-visual-line)
  (evil-global-set-key 'motion "k" 'evil-previous-visual-line)

  (evil-set-initial-state 'messages-buffer-mode 'normal)
  (evil-set-initial-state 'dashboard-mode 'normal))

my doom-mode-line config
(use-package doom-modeline
 :init (doom-modeline-mode 1)
 :custom ((doom-modeline-height 15)))

I try to ask gpt and search for google and change emacs to version 29.2, 29.4, but all have the same problem, and i change emacs to version 27.1, this time the plugin counsel have error "error (use-package): counsel/:catch: symbol’s function definition is void: defvar-1" , this is my ivy and counsel config
(use-package ivy
  :diminish
  :bind (("C-s" . swiper)
         :map ivy-minibuffer-map
         ("TAB" . ivy-alt-done)
         ("C-l" . ivy-alt-done)
         ("C-j" . ivy-next-line)
         ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
         :map ivy-switch-buffer-map
         ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
         ("C-l" . ivy-done)
         ("C-d" . ivy-switch-buffer-kill)
         :map ivy-reverse-i-search-map
         ("C-k" . ivy-previous-line)
         ("C-d" . ivy-reverse-i-search-kill))
  :config
  (ivy-mode 1))

(use-package counsel
    :config
    (counsel-mode 1))


now i use msys2, everything works good, it seems that using emacs on windows directly will encounter error everywhere...but now doom modeline still cannot work, have a error:Failed to install doom-modeline: Failed to verify signature: "compat-30.0.0.0.tar.sig"

It seems that you set native-comp-always-compile to t.  The precompiled version of Emacs available on GNU FTP does not support native compilation.

"it seems that using emacs on windows directly will encounter error everywhere" -- No, not really.  I had a great experience with Emacs on Windows, and you can too, as long as you don't skip the documentation and jump right in.  |||  "Failed to verify signature" -- See https://emacs-china.org/t/failed-to-verify-signature-archive-contents-sig/20508/4?u=shynur.  This is a common question, so please use a search engine before you ask it next time.
